# Question involving "do anything but"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have the following question:

> Do cat fanciers do anything but go to shows?

1. What does it mean? Does it mean:

> Do cat fanciers do anything else other than going to shows?

Or,

> Do cat fanciers even go to shows?

2. What should an apt relply be (I mean grammatically correct, regardless of whether it is factually true)?

Should it look like:

> Cat fanciers do go to pet shops to search for lingerie.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation “Do cat fanciers do anything else other than going to shows?” is correct.

Your proposed answer works, linguistically speaking, but it would be very strange to look for lingerie at a pet store.